# Feature map interaction between one layer and the next in CNNs

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

In an arbitrary hidden layer $i$ in a neural network, let's say there are 64 feature maps and in layer $i+1$ there are 128 feature maps. Does that mean, each of the 128 kernals in layer $i+1$ was applied on each of the feature maps from layer $i$?

Or are the number of kernels evenly divided so that there's something like 2 kernels being applied on every feature map to produce 128 feature maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernels are generally 3-dimensional (width x height x channels in previous layer). Each from 128 kernels in the l+1th was applied on each of the 64 features maps.

Btw, in the AlexNet paper you may find actually splitting of feature maps into two subgroups, each using only features from its own group, but that was just a hack to enable multi-gpu training.

Comment: So, then there are actually 128 kernals of dim 3x3x64 and it produces 128 2D feature maps (essentially, each kernal does a dot product over all channels)? And then the next layer uses kernals of size 3x3x128. Correct?

Comment: Exactly, that's it.